# monacaでsqliteデータベースにデータをプリセットしたものを組み込む

Tags: monaca, sqlite

monacaで別のGUIなどを使用して作成したsqliteデータベースファイルをプロジェクトファイルに組み込むことは可能ですか？
初回起動時にCREATE DATABASEなどでプログラムから作成する必要がありますか？

プリセットデータは10MB程度のサイズでアプリ内でもSQLを駆使してローカル端末でデータを検索・表示するようなアプリを作成しようとしています。
またデータ量は利用していくうちに増加します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova-sqlite-storage(https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)というプラグインを使えば実現できます。プリセットファイルを`www`フォルダに置いておくと、DBが存在しない時にそれを読み込みます。

ただ、カスタムプラグインの導入はゴールドプラン以上でないとできないので、それ以外のプランであれば自分でSQL文を書く必要がありそうです。